# Assign unique ID to Websocket and detect which connection closed

Tags: node.js, websocket, ws

I would like to assign a unique identifier to each Websocket connection on the server side. I want to be able to access this identifier upon detecting that a socket close. I'm using the [ws](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ws) and [nanoid](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nanoid)

```
wss.on('connection', (ws, req) => {
    ws.id = nanoid();
    console.log(ws.id);
    ws.on('close', (ws, req) => {
        console.log(ws.id);
    });
});
```

But unfortunately the second log in the `close` event listener prints `undefined`.

How do I maintain state of the WebSocket on the server side?

Thanks!

Comment: does actually `on('close', (ws, req))` gives you `ws` object there again?

Comment: Ah yes you're right! I was overwriting the `ws` in the outer scope which actually contains the ID. Thanks!

Comment: Happy to help =)

Answer (score 0):

You just need to send msg to the available connections

try to add :

```
wss.clients.forEach(client => {
    if(client !== ws && client.readyState === WebSocket.OPEN){
        client.send(data)
    }
})
```